# Regex or DOM for splitting an html string with just one element level dept

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom

I'm supposed to split a html string at any occurrence of a element "tag" with attribute "type" with value "findMe". There could be other random attributes and random innerHTML.

Valid match: `<tag type="findMe" any-other-attr="value">badabing</tag>`

An example of the intended outcome:

Input:

```
some html text <br> with some formatting<tag id="1" type="findMe">sample text</tag> yada <tag id="2" type="dontFidMe">sample text</tag>yada
```

Output:

- [0]: `some html text <br> with some formatting`
- [1]: `<tag id="2" type="dontFidMe"> yada yada`

I've started some progress by building a regular expression to split the string but it still has some issues. If I have adjacent "tag" elements and only one of them has the type attribute "findMe", the regular expression will greedily match both of them.

```
(?=<tag.*?type=(?:"|')findMe(?:"|').*?\/tag>)
```

I know I shouldn't parse html with regular expressions, but since I'm dealing with just one element dept level and I know before-hand what to expect, I wonder what could be most efficient in terms of performance and memory.

1. Parsing the html string to a in-memory DOM element and iterate all the nodes and splitting by tag elements with type attribute with value "findMe"?

OR

2. Creating a regular expression to find all tag elements with attribute value "findMe"? (if so, any help to improve the above regular expression is welcome)

Comment: Don't use Regex to parse HTML, lest you incur the wrath of [Tony the Pony!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/519413)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution I believe would be to change the `.` *inside* the tag, to match anything but the closing `>`.

```
(?=<tag[^>]*?type=["']findMe["'])
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BNcfBg/2). (The substitution with "\n[break]\n" is only to illustrate the split)

Note that an attribute containing `>` - like `<tag someattr="123>456" type="findMe">` would break it though. (That's one reason why regex *normally* isn't suitable for parsing HTML ;)

But I **guess** the regex approach would be beneficial in your (simple) case.

**Edit** Altered the regex101 example to better illustrate the solution.